# What do I put in the "compute capability list" field when configuring Tensorflow?

Tags: build, configuration, tensorflow

I'm building Tensorflow from source, and it asks me to

```
Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size.
[Default is: "3.5,5.2"]:
```

I figured out that it has to do with my cards compute capability (which is 5.0, btw), but clearly that's not what it wants, because it's a number, not a list. I couldn't find any explanations, nor am I skilled enough to understand it from the source code. What should I put in there?

Comment: Can you just put 5.0 there?

Comment: I guess I can; but is such a random guess better than the default? I would think that the default is default for a reason, and unless I understand what I do, I'd prefer not changing it.

Comment: Compute capability is based on your card, which is 5.0. It should be your best choice. 3.5 is too low (doesn't use the full features of your card) and 5.2 is too high (not supported by your card); in either case, I believe the binary code would be recompiled with 5.0 just in time before the execution on the GPU. If you directly use 5.0, it won't trigger just in time compilation and will use more optimized offline compilation.

Comment: @YaoZhang, Oh, okay, I think I understand. Mind putting that as an answer so I can accept it? By the way, why is it a list then, if it's better to use the exact value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comments as an answer:

You can put 5.0 there, which is the compute capability that your card supports and should be your best choice. 3.5 is too low (doesn't use the full features of your card) and 5.2 is too high (not supported by your card); in either case, I believe the binary code would be re-compiled with 5.0 just in time before the execution on the GPU. If you directly use 5.0, it won't trigger just in time compilation and will use more optimized offline compilation.

If you provide a list, say 3.5,5.0,5.2, it will compile for all three compute capabilities offline and allow the offline compiled (more optimized) code to run on GPU cards that support either 3.5, or 5.0, or 5.2, without triggering less optimized just-in-time compilation. The cost of putting more compute capabilities in the list is the increased offline compilation time and binary size.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

and find out your GPU. You will find the compute capability, like mine was 6.1